# Grouping Points by Location using ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, routing, network-analyst, arcgis-10.2

What I am trying to achieve is pictured below, but programmatically. I have a table of 400 locations from which I eyed out an equal amount of points and divided them into 3 routes with Zip Code Tabulation Areas as my zones.

Are there any toolsets that group points by location, up until a certain number of records?

In my example I have a ceiling of 140 locations per route.

I am using ArcMap 10.2 Desktop Advanced

[image: Routing Problem]

Comment: Could you please include in your post which version of ArcMap you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In lack of an answer, our [FleetEngine](http://www.routeware.dk/fleetengine/fleetengine.php) tool can do this, using VRP techniques. But for such a simple case, it can also be done using our RW Net 4 library, the [cluster1](http://www.routeware.dk/rwnet4/help/cluster1.htm) method in particular.